# left div fill remaining horizontal space?

Tags: css

I have two divs

`#left`, and `#right`.

the right div has a fixed width.

How can i cause the left div to take up all remaining horizontal space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Float the `#right` div within `#left`, and leave `#left` without a float. Add right-padding to `#left` of the width of `#right`, if you wish for the space below the floated `#right` to be empty.

You *may* also need to add a negative right margin to the `#right` element equal to the right-padding of left to pull it up to the right edge of `#left` too. Alternatively to using a negative margin you could set `#left` with `position: relative` and add `position: absolute` to `#right` to the top left of `#left` (also with the padding on `#left`).

Comment: i did a very similar setup,

right is inside left,
right is floated right
right has a margin-right of negative its own width,
left has a margin-right of #rights, width.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but this is no solution for me - I can't nest #right within #left because their backgrounds will overlap and I have semi-transparent backgrounds - I need a solutions that keeps the original nesting.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a table, or the CSS display:table-cell; property?

Comment: Using display:table-cell is actually a lot less negative margins, right padding, etc. See example here: http://jsbin.com/oburey/4/edit Fairly simple.